# Rearrange an array to have all elements next to each other in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of elements and I'm trying to arrange it so that there are no null spaces in the array.

For example, if I have a string array...

`String[] myArray = { "apple", null, "pen", "pineapple", null, "book" };`

I want the elements in the array to be next to each other without any null spaces.

This is my code...

```
    String[] Array = {"apple","","pen","pineapple","", "book"};

    System.out.println("The array before:");
    for (int k = 0; k < Array.length; k++)
    {
        System.out.println(Array[k]);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < Array.length; j++)
    {
        if (Array[j] == null)
        {
            Array[j] = Array[j + 1];
        }
    }

    System.out.println(" ");

    System.out.println("The array after:");
    for (int i = 0; i < Array.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(Array[i]);
    }

    /*The array before:
      apple
      null
      pen
      pineapple
      null
      book

      The array after:
      apple
      pen
      pen
      pineapple
      book
      book*/
```

Comment: hint : An empty string **is not null**

Comment: Is this a homework-question where you have to stick with arrays or more a real life thing?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want to re-arrange the array so that empty strings appear at the end of it. This is similar to the partitioning algorithm used by Quicksort. We can partition the array in one linear scan by maintaining three sections of the array: non-empty strings (to the left of `firstEmpty`), empty strings (between `firstEmpty` and `i`), and unexplored (to the right of `i`).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] array = {"apple", "", "pen", "pineapple", "", "book"};

    int firstEmpty = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        if (!array[i].isEmpty()) {
            swap(array, firstEmpty, i);
            firstEmpty++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}

private static void swap(final String[] array, final int i, final int j) {
    String tmp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = tmp;
}
```

The output is

```
[apple, pen, pineapple, book, , ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(Array));
    list.removeAll(Arrays.asList(""));
//  list.removeAll(Arrays.asList("",null));// to remove "" and null
    System.out.println(list);
```

Prints this

```
[apple, pen, pineapple, book]
```

---

Modified answer as per the question change

```
for (int i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
    if ("".equals(Array[i]) || Array[i] == null) {
        //String[] Array = { "apple", "", "pen", "pineapple", "", "book", null };
        //no condition given when the last element is null , hence returning null
        Array[i] = (i < Array.length - 2) ? Array[i + 1] : null;
    }
}
```

Before : apple  pen pineapple  book null

After : apple pen pen pineapple book book null

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the stream-api with filtering...

```
String[] filteredArray = Arrays.stream(yourArray)
                               .filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank)
                               .toArray(String[]::new);
```

StringUtils is part of the apache commons library and the suggested way to do basic String checks. `isNotBlank` checks is the supplied String is not either `null`, empty or consisting only of whitespace.

Your solution fails in several ways:

1. You check for null instead of empty strings
2. You modify your existing array duplicating the entries after a blank String

Comment: I believe `filter().toArray()` return `Object[]`

Answer (score 0):

This will also check the whitespaces and convert array in your required format.

```
String[] array = {"apple"," ","pen","pineapple","", "book"};
array = Arrays.stream(array)
            .filter(i -> i != null && i.trim().length() > 0)
            .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

*prevents null strings, empty strings and strings containing only white space codepoints

with lambda – w/o any external libs*

```
Arrays.stream( myArray ).filter( s -> s != null && ! s.isBlank() )
    .toArray( String[]::new );
```

`isBlank()` since Java 11

gets: `[apple, pen, pineapple, book]`

Answer (score -1):

Your Problem is that you compare to `null` instead of comparing to the empty string.

If you check for empty string it should work.

```
for (int j = 0; j < Array.length; j++)
{
    if (Array[j].equals(""))
    {
        Array[j] = Array[j + 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: `Array[j] = Array[j + 1];`  ?? this  seriously _should work_ ??

Comment: As @Nod said, he should use another array anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Your array[j] is not null when you put in the array "", the element is empty. You have to check if it is null or empty.

You can also use the lambdas but the best is understand why the control fails.

try this :

```
for (int j = 0; j < Array.length; j++)
    {
        if (Array[j] == null || Array[j].equals(""))
        {
            Array[j] = Array[j + 1];
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Array[j] = Array[j + 1];`  ?? This is surely not the way to do it

Comment: Yes, of course, it will not work, but it answers the problem of the control of the element. For the modification of the array it is notable that this is nonconforming. He has to create another array anyway.